# 'in' and '==' in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What's the difference in the usage of `in` and `==` in python ?
I want to explore more while comparing with a **single character**.

```
if gender in "M":
    print "Male"

if gender == "M":
    print "Male"
```

Of the following, which one can be more beneficial to use, `in` or `==`?

Comment: The difference is that they test for different things. `==` tests for equality, `in` tests that one is contained within the other. For instance, if `gender` is `'M'`, then `gender in 'Monkey'` will be `True`, but `gender == 'Monkey'` will be `False`

Comment: You have to be careful about what you mean by "contains" with the `str` definition of `in`. `"b" in "bar"` is true, as is `"ba" in "bar"`, but not `"br" in "bar"`.

Comment: @chepner - Yes, I realise it's not *quite* as simple as I stated, but the difference between the two operators is clear. Although, IMO, no sensible person would expect `'br' in 'bar'` to be true.

Comment: @SiHa It's not that big a stretch, if you think `"ba" in "bar"` is true because `"ba"` is a just a subset, not a subsequence, of `"bar"`. I've seen people expect `in` to behave like `<=` with sets.

Answer (score 0):

in your case there is no need to use in, since you are comparing **one** character.

use **==**

Answer (score 0):

When you use "in", it means one of the object in the list(in "money" means any of m,o,n,e,y)but ==means whole money.

Answer (score 0):

Use `==`:

```
>>> "" in "M"
True
```